# Elementary embeddings

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Im not quite sure I understand elementary embeddings right. Say M elementary embeds into N and $M \models\varphi$, does it follow that $N \models \varphi$ or is there a problem with existential formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes that follows.

This is really direct from the definition of elementary embedding.

> **Definition.** A function $f: M \to N$ is an *elementary embedding* if for every formula $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and all $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in M$ we have
> $$ M \models \phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad N \models \phi(f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n)).$$

So if $\phi$ is a sentence, i.e. contains no free variables, then this simplifies to
$$
M \models \phi \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad N \models \phi.
$$
In particular this means that $M$ and $N$ are *elementarily equivalent*, which means that they satisfy exactly the same sentences.

You might be confused with embeddings. Let me recall that definition (well, one of the equivalent definitions).

> **Definition.** A function $f: M \to N$ is an *embedding* if for every quantifier-free formula $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and all $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in M$ we have
> $$ M \models \phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad N \models \phi(f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n)).$$

Note that in this definition we only care about quantifier-free formulas. The following fact is where existential formulas and universal formulas come into play.

> **Fact.** Let $f: M \to N$ be an embedding and let $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a formula and let $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in M$.
>
> 1. If $\phi$ is an existential formula then $M \models \phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \implies N \models \phi(f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n))$.
> 2. If $\phi$ is a universal formula then $M \models \phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \Longleftarrow N \models \phi(f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n))$.

**Proof.** Exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains it!